# M2DOC : initialization of the variable self

Tags: m2doc

I would like to set the self variable to a specific PhysicalComponent in my model.
For this, in my template wordx I set:
m:var:self to pa::PhysicalComponent
I imported my template in Capella 1.4.0.
After initialize document configuration, I want to set the variable self to a specific PhysicalComponent of my model, but it doesn't work.

With the previous version of M2DOc it was possible but with this new one (3.0.0) it doesn't work.

Is it a bug of M2DOC ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a bug. There is a fix on the [M2Doc 3.0.x maintenance branch](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/tree/3.0.x).

A nightly update site with the fix is available [here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/obeo-m2doc-releases/3.0.x/nightly/repository/).